# Spring Boot @RequestScope and Hibernate schema based multi-tenancy

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, multi-tenant

I'm working on a schema based multi-tenant app, in which I want to resolve the Tenant Identifier using a @RequestScope bean. My understanding is that @RequestScope uses/injects proxies for the request scoped beans, wherever they are referred (e.g. in other singleton beans). However, this is not working in the @Component that implements  `CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver` and I get the following error when I start my service,

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ScopeNotActiveException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.userContext': Scope 'request' is not active for the current thread; 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
```

Following are the relevant pieces of code.

```
@Component
public class CurrentTenant implements CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver {

    @Autowired
    private UserContext userContext;
    
    @Override
    public String resolveCurrentTenantIdentifier() {

        return Optional.of(userContext)
                       .map(u -> u.getDomain())
                       .get();
    }


@Component
@RequestScope
public class UserContext {

    private UUID   id;
    private String domain;
```

My questions,

1. Isn't the proxy for the @RequestScope injected (by default)? Do I need to do anything more?
2. Is Hibernate/Spring trying to establish a connection to the DB at startup (even when there is no tenant available)?

**Hibernate properties:**

```
HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.remove(AvailableSettings.DEFAULT_SCHEMA);
        properties.put(AvailableSettings.MULTI_TENANT, MultiTenancyStrategy.SCHEMA);
        properties.put(AvailableSettings.MULTI_TENANT_IDENTIFIER_RESOLVER, tenantResolver);
        properties.put(AvailableSettings.MULTI_TENANT_CONNECTION_PROVIDER, connectionProvider);
```

For the time being, I'm preventing the NullPointerException by checking if we are in the RequestContext. However, a connection still gets established to the master database (although I've explicitly specified the dialect and am not specifying hbm2ddl.auto). Since this connection is not associated with any schema, I'd like to avoid making it, so that it does not look for any tables that it won't find anyways.
What seems to be happenning is that when a HTTP request is received, hibernate is trying to resolve the current tenant identifier, even before my @RequestScope bean is created (and even before my @RestController method is called.) If a provide the default connection to the databse, I then get the following error. If I don't provide a connection, it throws an exception and aborts.

```
2021-09-26 11:55:44.882  WARN 19759 --- [nio-8082-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42P01
2021-09-26 11:55:44.882 ERROR 19759 --- [nio-8082-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: relation "employees" does not exist
  Position: 301
2021-09-26 11:55:44.884 ERROR 19759 --- [nio-8082-exec-2] o.t.n.controller.EmployeeController      : Exception: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
```

Comment: 1) you need an http request to be able to inject something with request scope. 2) yes, database pools are initialized on the startup usually, with the multitenant approach you are force to use one pool per tenant or use an user in the connection pool whicih sees all the schema/teants in the database

Comment: Add your hibernate configuraiton. Make sure you specify the dialect and don't try to validate the schema. If that is the case disable it or set a default datasource. If you don't hibernate will try to get a connection very early on to determine the schema (and validate for instance) or to determine the database to set the dialect.

Comment: Hi Marten/Javier, I've updated my question with hibernate properties. Can you please take a look? It's not clear why hibernate is creating the connections up-front and as expected (in my code), when I actually send a request, it tries to use those existing connections and fails to find the tables.

Comment: Maybe OSIV is the problem here? If so, maybe you have to set the UserContext properties before the OSIV filter runs.

Comment: Thanks @ChristianBeikov for pointing me towards OSIV; I'll look it up. Meanwhile, I'm currently "avoiding" both problems (viz., tenant resolution at startup and tenant resolution before injection of request-scope bean) by using RequestContext.